Nicegui, pyinstaller and matplotlib: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_svg'
I want to build a onefile app with pyinstaller using the nicegui package.
Here my main.py code:
import numpy as np

from nicegui import ui

ui.label("Hello from Pyinstaller")

with ui.matplotlib(figsize=(3, 2)).figure as fig:
    x = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0)
    y = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-x)
    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.plot(x, y, "-")

ui.run(native=True, reload=False, title="PyInstaller Test")

and here the build.py I am using
import nicegui
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess
import os

static_dir = Path(nicegui.__file__).parent


cmd = [
    "py",
    "-m",
    "PyInstaller",
    "main.py",  # your main file with ui.run()
    "--name",
    "myapp",  # name of your app
    "--onefile",
    #'--windowed', # prevent console appearing, only use with ui.run(native=True, ...)
    "--add-data",
    f"{Path(nicegui.__file__).parent}{os.pathsep}nicegui",
]
subprocess.call(cmd)


Went I launch build.py I have the error:  No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_svg'. but matplotlib is installed. When I run main.py (with ui.run()), the app works fine.
I don't have find any solution online. I also try to re-install pyinstaller, nicegui and matplotlib.
I also try
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
I don't know if I am missing something.

check if you can run (in console) file created by PyInstaller. If it works then don't bother this error. And if it can't run then maybe it will show what modules you have to add manually to build.py. Maybe you will have to add some module for SVG or maybe even some C/C++ libraries for SVG

did you check this error message in Google? I found (using Google) Pyinstaller 5.0: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_svg' · Issue #6760 · pyinstaller/pyinstaller
